# Do crowd-sourced charity funds work without a social network?

Tags: charity, crowdfunding

Someone I know and respect is going through a serious emergency and needs financial help.

He has been very sick for years, and is socially isolated.  He only has a couple friends.

I am thinking about setting up a crowd-sourced charity fund (aka crowdfunding) for my friend, perhaps using a service like GoFundMe.

But since very few people know him, he does not have any social network to whom I can advertise his fund.

I will tell all my friends and colleagues about his fund, but none of them know him, and I'm not sure if the people I know are as compassionate as myself.

I want to help him the best I can, but I don't want to waste my time and energy.

Do crowd-sourced funds like this attract enough donations from strangers, or will this avenue of generating funds for him be a waste of my time?

*(If it does have a reasonable chance of being successful, in the comments you may consider pointing me to which crowd-sourced fund sites will have the greatest chance of helping him.)*

Comment: It's hard to prove a negative, but while I have contributed to cash-strapped friends I would be more annoyed and suspicious if asked to support a stranger... Unless a friend vouched for them; then I'd probably just be uninterested. If it looks too easy to be true, it probably is too easy to be true, even if it isn't exploitative or a complete scam. I'd be far more likely to donate to a respectable charity which serves that community.

Comment: This isn't really about money - more about social networking.

Comment: @DJClayworth I'm interested in the fund raising (money) side when the social networking side will not be present.

Answer (score 4):

> Do crowd-sourced funds like this attract enough donations from strangers, or will this avenue of generating funds for him be a waste of my time?

It depends. There is no simple answer. There are cases where a celebrity endorsed / requested help for a critically ill patient, and the amount of donations that flowed in were 100 times more than what was required!

If your Social network is very strong / large and that of the other few people he knows is strong / large, there is no harm in trying.

In my view the effort is small compared to the potential reward. You would at least have the satisfaction that you did all you could.

Comment: *In my view the effort is small compared to the potential reward. You would at least have the satisfaction that you did all you could.*  Thanks.  Those two sentences you wrote are quite useful.